# Passive infinitive + verb third form

Tags: modal-verbs, passive-voice, perfect-constructions

Which kind of stretchers is it. Passive infinitive + verb third form. As it is written here (may have been decimated). May have been is passive infinitive and decimated is verb third form.

Comment: I have never encountered the term "stretchers" -- I take it that you are asking for the name of the construction.

Answer (score 1):

> may have been decimated

*May have been* is not by itself a passive, but a modal perfect. Followed by a past participle it **becomes** a passive: in full, a ***present-tense*** (or non-past-tense) ***modal perfect passive construction***.

- *may* is the present-tense verb in the construction, a modal. Modals possess only two forms, both tensed.
- *have* is the perfect auxiliary, cast in the infinitive form because it is the complement of a modal verb
- *been* is the passive auxiliary, cast in the perfect participle form because it is the complement of the perfect auxiliary
- *decimated* is the lexical verb, cast in the perfect participle form because it is the complement of the passive auxiliary.

Building the construction backwards, in the present tense:

    `PRESENT: [SUBJ] decimates                tensed lexical verb 
    PASSIVE: [SUBJ] is decimated             tensed BE + PaPpl of lexical verb
    PERFECT: [SUBJ] has been decimated       tensed HAVE + PaPpl of BE + PaPpl of lexical verb
    MODAL:   [SUBJ] may have been decimated  tensed MAY + Inf of HAVE + PaPpl of BE + PaPpl
                                                                            of lexical verb`

Comment: Re "*may* is the present-tense verb in the construction, a modal. Modals possess only two forms, both tensed", can you explain what does it mean that modals are tensed? Does it mean that they have a time reference (either past, present or future), or that the *morphological* form of the verb corresponds to the present or the past tense? If the latter, how? // Additional reading on this topic would be appreciated! :)